# How write fail-test (J-Unit) throwing JAXBException when unmarshaller initialized in constructor?

Tags: java, exception, junit, jaxb

I tryied to write fail-test for simple code like this:

```
public class XmlDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T>
{
    private final Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    public XmlDeserializer(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        try
        {
            this.unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz).createUnmarshaller();
        }
        catch (JAXBException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

when in constructor we catch JAXBExeption, but it turned out to be not so easy.

I tried @Test(expected = RuntimeException),  @Rule for expected exception, passed different classes to the constructor. I couldn't use reflection or Mockito in this case.

I spent a couple of hours on this, but couldn't find a solution on google or Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Later I came up with a solution and decided to share it, I hope it will helps someone.

I got the desired exception by substituting an interface instead of a class. Just like that:

```
public class XmlDeserializerTest
{
@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void constructor_CreatingUnmarshallerFail_Test() throws RuntimeException
{
    new XmlDeserializer<>(Runnable.class);
}
```

So we have the necessary exception when passing any interface to the constructor